# Accessing Camera and Stores Images Marshmallow

Tags: java, android, camera

I have this code which allows users to access the camera to take photos and select images from gallery, it works on my Sony Xperia Z3 running Android 5.1.1.

I now have upgraded to a Nexus 5X running Android 6.0, but when i try to use the camera or save an image i get errors any help?

My Code to use Camera

```
Intent CameraImage = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
Intent SelectedCameraImage = Intent.createChooser(CameraImage, "Take A Photo With");
startActivityForResult(SelectedCameraImage, SELECTED);
```

My Result Handler

```
public void onActivityResult(int RequestCode, int ResultCode, Intent Data) {
    if (ResultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (RequestCode == SELECTED) {
            Uri SelectedImageUri = Data.getData();
            SelectedImagePath = getPath(SelectedImageUri);
            Log.d("DatabaseOperations", "Image Path :  " + SelectedImagePath);
            Img.setImageURI(SelectedImageUri);

            try {
                FileInputStream FileInpStream = new FileInputStream(SelectedImagePath);
                BufferedInputStream BufInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(FileInpStream);
                DBByte = new byte[BufInputStream.available()];
                BufInputStream.read(DBByte);
                Log.d("DatabaseOperations", "Image Size :  " + DBByte.length + " KB");
            }

            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("DatabaseOperations", "Error :  " + SelectedImagePath);
                Log.d("DatabaseOperations", e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
    }
}

public String getPath(Uri Uris) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor Cursor = managedQuery(Uris, projection, null, null, null);
    int ColumnIndex = Cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    Cursor.moveToFirst();
    return Cursor.getString(ColumnIndex);
}
```

My Manifest Permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission-sdk-23 android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

The Errors (Logcat)

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-01 22:12:44.071 3768-3768/rajancorporations.database E/AndroidRuntime: Process: rajancorporations.database, PID: 3768
03-01 22:12:44.071 3768-3768/rajancorporations.database E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE cmp=com.google.android.GoogleCamera/com.android.camera.CaptureActivity } from ProcessRecord{c9f94d7 3768:rajancorporations.database/u0a80} (pid=3768, uid=10080) with revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA
03-01 22:12:44.071 3768-3768/rajancorporations.database E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1620)
03-01 22:12:44.071 3768-3768/rajancorporations.database E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1573)
03-01 22:12:44.071 3768-3768/rajancorporations.database E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:2658)
03-01 22:12:44.071 3768-3768/rajancorporations.database E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1507)
03-01 22:12:44.071 3768-3768/rajancorporations.database E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3930)
03-01 22:12:44.071 3768-3768/rajancorporations.database E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3890)
03-01 22:12:44.071 3768-3768/rajancorporations.database E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:784)
03-01 22:12:44.071 3768-3768/rajancorporations.database E/AndroidRuntime:     at rajancorporations.database.Reg$2.onClick(Reg.java:75)
03-01 22:12:44.071 3768-3768/rajancorporations.database E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
03-01 22:12:44.071 3768-3768/rajancorporations.database E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153)
03-01 22:12:44.071 3768-3768/rajancorporations.database E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
03-01 22:12:44.071 3768-3768/rajancorporations.database E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-01 22:12:44.071 3768-3768/rajancorporations.database E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
03-01 22:12:44.071 3768-3768/rajancorporations.database E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
03-01 22:12:44.071 3768-3768/rajancorporations.database E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-01 22:12:44.071 3768-3768/rajancorporations.database E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
03-01 22:12:44.071 3768-3768/rajancorporations.database E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Always show the errors.

Comment: it just says for image storage /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/RajanDP.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Comment: What errors are you getting? Is your `compileSdkVersion = 23`? If so, you need to make sure you are asking for [permission in run-time](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

Comment: and for the camera java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE cmp=com.google.android.GoogleCamera/com.android.camera.CaptureActivity } from ProcessRecord{c9f94d7 3768:rajancorporations.database/u0a80} (pid=3768, uid=10080) with revoked permission android.permission.CAMERA

Comment: my errors are shown in the comments and i am building in API 23 max but API 22 min. the code is ok in API 22 Devices but not on API 23 Devices

Comment: It's advisable to edit the question and format your logcat errors as code to make them easy to read.

Comment: ` java.lang.SecurityException` typically means the user has not yet granted permission. Requesting for permission in run-time should solve your problem. See the link above.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my complete code for taking image from camera or Gallery and it is working fine in marshmallow with others.

Here i am Declaring Varriables

```
protected static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 0;
protected static final int GALLERY_REQUEST = 1;
private static final int REQUEST_ACESS_STORAGE=3;
private static final int REQUEST_ACESS_CAMERA=2;
private Uri uri;
```

Here i have some Methods for permission in marshmallow

```
public static boolean checkPermission(String permission, Context context) {
    int statusCode = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission);
    return statusCode == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}

public static void requestPermission(AppCompatActivity activity, String[] permission, int requestCode) {
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(activity, permission[0])) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Application need permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, permission, requestCode);
}

public static void requestPermission(Fragment fragment, String[] permission, int requestCode) {
    fragment.requestPermissions(permission, requestCode);
}
```

My onclick method

```
if (v.getId()==R.id.idOfPhoto){
            handleCamera();
        }
```

Details of handle camera method

```
private void handleCamera(){
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (checkPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, this)) {
                startDilog();
            }else{
               requestPermission(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},REQUEST_ACESS_STORAGE);
            }
        }else{
            startDilog();
        }
    }
```

startdilog method

```
private void startDilog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder myAlertDilog = new AlertDialog.Builder(YourActivity.this);
    myAlertDilog.setTitle("Upload picture option..");
    myAlertDilog.setMessage("Where to upload picture????");
    myAlertDilog.setPositiveButton("Gallery", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent picIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT,null);
            picIntent.setType("image/*");
            picIntent.putExtra("return_data",true);
            startActivityForResult(picIntent,GALLERY_REQUEST);
        }
    });
    myAlertDilog.setNegativeButton("Camera", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
                if(checkPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA,YourActivity.this)){
                    openCameraApplication();
                }else{
                    requestPermission(YourActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},REQUEST_ACESS_CAMERA);
                }
            }else{
                openCameraApplication();
            }
        }
    });
    myAlertDilog.show();
}
```

openCameraApplication method

```
private void openCameraApp() {
    Intent picIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (picIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!= null){
        startActivityForResult(picIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

Rest of code

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (data != null) {
                uri = data.getData();
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                try {
                    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri), null, options);
                    options.inSampleSize =calculateInSampleSize(options, 100, 100);
                    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri), null, options);
                    imageview.setImageBitmap(image);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cancelled",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cancelled",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (data.hasExtra("data")) {
                Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                uri = getImageUri(YourActivity.this, bitmap);
                File finalFile = new File(getRealPathFromUri(uri));
                imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } else if (data.getExtras() == null) {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "No extras to retrieve!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

                BitmapDrawable thumbnail = new BitmapDrawable(
                        getResources(), data.getData().getPath());
                owner_pic.setImageDrawable(thumbnail);

            }

        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cancelled",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

private String getRealPathFromUri(Uri tempUri) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(tempUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
private Uri getImageUri(YourActivity youractivity, Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(youractivity.getContentResolver(), bitmap, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);

public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                    && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }
        return inSampleSize;
    }



@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if(requestCode==REQUEST_ACESS_STORAGE && grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        startDilog();
    }
    if(requestCode==REQUEST_ACESS_CAMERA && grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        openCameraApp();
    }
}
```

it's working fine in witth all devices..

Comment: Very Good Solution but has some errors of typing in calling functions.

Answer (score 1):

First, you assume that `Data.getData()` is meaningful here. [There is no `Uri` returned by `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, according to the specification](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html#ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE). Your options are either to supply `EXTRA_OUTPUT` (in which case, the image should be where you indicate in that extra), or to get a thumbnail back from `Data.getExtra("data")`. There may be a few camera apps that do return a `Uri`. But there are over *8,000* Android device models, with hundreds, if not thousands, of different default camera apps. The user might also be having your request be handled by a third-party camera app. Most camera apps will give you a `null` value for `Data.getData()`.

Second, even *if* you get a `Uri`, you assume that the `Uri` is known to the `MediaStore`. That is not required.

Third, even *if* you get a `Uri` and it is *is* known to the `MediaStore`, you assume that the `DATA` column is a path to a local file that you can access. This is not required. For example, it might be a path to removable storage, which you cannot access on Android 4.4+.

To address those three problems, use `EXTRA_OUTPUT` to designate where you want the camera to store the picture, and get rid of `getPath()` and your dependence upon the `Uri`.

Fourth, when working with external storage on Android 6.0+, if your `targetSdkVersion` is 23 or higher, you need to request `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` or `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` [from the user at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/cant-get-the-permission). The same holds true for the `CAMERA` permission.

Fifth, do not have `<uses-permission>` *and* `<uses-permission-sdk-23>` for the same permissions. In your case, use `<uses-permission>`.

Comment: its easier to store the image path to a database which is what i do with the selected image, and i'll try the run time permissions, how will i do this in the activity code, can i see an example

Comment: @RexDough: "its easier to store the image path to a database which is what i do with the selected image" -- what is "easier" does not matter. If you rely upon the `Uri`, **you may not have an image path**, as **you may not get a `Uri`**. "how will i do this in the activity code" -- https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Permissions/tutorial/finish/RuntimePermTutorial